# Selecting Values from same table with different condition

Tags: mysql

I have a table where I need to get aggregate values based on status. I need a sum where `status =1` as one column and `status =2` as different column.

Here is my table sample:

```
| id  | name  | did  | amount   | status |
| 1   | t1    | 2    | 100      |1       |
| 2   | t2    | 3    | 200      |1       |
| 3   | t3    | 2    | 300      |4       |
| 4   | t4    | 2    | 100      |1       |
| 5   | t5    | 3    | 100      |4       |
| 6   | t6    | 3    | 100      |4       |
```

I need to get sum of `did` 3 and `status` 1 as one column , sum of `did` 2 and `status` 4 as another column and balance.

I have to write two queries for this, is it possible to combine them into a single query to get values?

```
SELECT SUM(totalamount) AS amount1 FROM table1  WHERE status  IN (1) GROUP BY did
SELECT SUM(totalamount) AS amount2 FROM table1  WHERE status  IN (4) GROUP BY did
```

My desired output is:

```
   | did | amount1  | amount2  | 
   |  2  | 200      | 300      |       
   |  3  | 200      | 200      |
```

How can I achieve this in one query?

Answer (score 1):

You do that using the `case` expression:

```
SELECT 
  did, 
  SUM(CASE status WHEN 1 THEN totalamount END) AS amount1,
  SUM(CASE status WHEN 4 THEN totalamount END) AS amount2
FROM table1  
GROUP BY did
```